# Xcode high score issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having an issue saving my high scores in my game.

For example after the first game, where I am starting with a high score of zero, the high score becomes the score. However, after subsequent games the high score is not always getting overwritten at the correct time. Why is that?

Here's the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *myscore = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstring"];
    _scoreMade.text = myscore;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults4 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *highscore1 = [defaults4 objectForKey:@"highscore"];

    if(myscore > highscore1) {
        _highestScore.text = myscore;
       NSString *savestring33 = _scoreMade.text;
       NSUserDefaults *defaults4 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
       [defaults4 setObject:savestring33 forKey:@"highscore"];
       [defaults4 synchronize];
       NSLog (@"new score");
    }
    if(highscore1 > myscore){
        _highestScore.text = highscore1;
        NSLog (@"no new score");    
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm unsure what the question actually is. From the code provided, I don't see any references to 3, 5, or 7. Please provide more code or rephrase your question

Comment: @kamran619 - that was an example when running the code. I pressed the button five times and scored "5" and received a high score of "5" - Then I played again and pressed the button three times and scored "3" and received a high score of "5" - Then I played again and pressed the button seven times and scored "7" and received a high score of "5"

Comment: The issue is that you are comparing NSStrings and not numbers

Comment: @WyattMufson how would I fix it then?

Comment: Convert the strings into an int value and then compare. The code is pretty straight forward, and I could provide it, but I think that would take the point of looking it up/learning how to do it away from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
if(myscore > highscore1) {
```

Should be:

```
if([myscore intValue] > [highscore1 intValue]) {
```

And this:

```
if(highscore1 > myscore) {
```

Should be:

```
if([highscore1 intValue] > [myscore intValue]) {
```